# Spring Security for URL with permitAll() and expired Auth Token

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring 4 with Spring Security, custom GenericFilterBean and AuthenticationProvider implementations. I have mostly secured URLs with the exception of a URL to create new session: ***/v2/session*** (e.g. login based on the username and password and returns Auth Token to be used in the subsequent requests that require authentication) configured as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.api.security"})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ApiAuthenticationProvider apiAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private AuthTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter authTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint apiAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(apiAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(authTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) // Main auth filter
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v2/session").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(apiAuthenticationEntryPoint);
}
}
```

The ***authTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter*** runs on every request and gets Token from the request header:

```
/**
 * Main Auth Filter. Always sets Security Context if the Auth token Header is not empty
 */
@Component
public class AuthTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final String token = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader(RequestHeaders.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    try {
            AuthenticationToken authRequest = new AuthenticationToken(token);

              SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authRequest);
        }
    } catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response); // continue down the chain
}
```

}

The custom ***apiAuthenticationProvider*** will try to authenticate all requests based on the token provided in the header and if authentication is unsuccessful - throws AccessException and client will receive HTTP 401 response:

```
@Component
public class ApiAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
private remoteAuthService remoteAuthService;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    AuthenticationToken authRequest = (AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String identity = null;

    try {
        identity = remoteAuthService.getUserIdentityFromToken(authRequest.getToken());
    } catch (AccessException e) {
        throw new InvalidAuthTokenException("Cannot get user identity from the token", e);
    }

    return new AuthenticationToken(identity, authRequest.getToken(), getGrantedAuthorites());
    }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine for the requests that require authentication. This works fine for the ***/v2/session*** request without the Authentication Header in it. However, for the ***/v2/session*** request that has an expired Auth Token in the header (or in the cookie - not shown in the code samples; this may happen sometimes if the client didn't clear the headers or continues sending cookies with requests) the security context will be initialized and ***apiAuthenticationProvider*** will throw an exception and respond with HTTP 401 to the client.

Since ***/v2/session*** has been configured as

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v2/session").permitAll()
```

I would expect Spring Security to determine that before calling ApiAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(). What should be the way for the filter or auth provider to ignore/not throw the exception for the URLs configured as permitAll()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spring security filters get triggered before the request authorisation checks are performed. For the authorisation checks to work, it is assumed that the request has been through the filters and the Spring security context has been set (or not, depending on whether authentication credentials have been passed in).

In your filter you have check that continues with the filter chain processing if the token is not there. Unfortunately, if it is, then it will be passed to your provider for authentication, which throws an exception because the token has expired thus you're getting the 401.

Your best bet is to bypass filter execution for the URLs that you consider public. You can either do this in the filter itself or in your configuration class. Add the following method to your `SecurityConfig` class:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
  webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v2/session");
}
```

What this will do, is bypass your `AuthTokenHeaderAuthenticationFilter` completely for `POST /v2/sessions` URL.

Comment: Check out this thread, it also answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917671/add-http-security-filter-in-java-config

Comment: @grigori How do I ensure that my requests still go through the rest of the security filter chain such as for csrf protection etc. I need to have that URL in permitAll() then. right? In summary, How would I configure public requests that require rest of the spring security filter chain services?

Comment: 3 years and still not a better solution, this concerns me a bit!